# Format hh:mm with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date-formatting

I'm using

```
CONVERT( CHAR(5), DATEADD(n, value),0), 108)
```

to convert minutes to a `hh:mm` format, but it breaks when I have more minutes then fit in 24hrs. E.g. `1440` gives `00:00` instead of `24:00`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the `%` modulo operator:

```
select cast(n/60 as varchar(20)) + ':' + 
       right('0' + cast(n%60 as varchar(2)), 2)
```

Comment: Works almost, except it gives eg 24:0 instead of 24:00. Any chance to fix that?

Comment: You can prefix the minutes with `'0'` and take the rightmost two characters, answer edited

Comment: Fair enough. Was hoping for a cleaner solution, guess code isn't always poetry. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
declare @minutes int
select @minutes = 1440

select convert(varchar, @minutes/60) + ':' + right ('0'+convert(varchar, @minutes%60), 2)
```